# JDBC resource name being modified by container ('_pm' being appended to it)

Tags: java, jdbc, cloudbees

I'm trying to get a very simple web application deployed to a JavaEE Web Profile stack on CloudBees.  I've created a database which will be used.

I've created my WAR file, and deployed it into a Glassfish3 profile, but it errors out. I've also tried a JBoss one, and that fails as well, but with a different error.  I've bound the database to the application using the SDK (not the CloudBees XML file (as it sounds like thats deprecated).  But regardless the application keeps failing to deploy (even after restarting) with this error:

```
[#|2013-02-25T11:03:57.584+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;|Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : jdbc/resmandb__pm
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/resmandb__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.validateResource(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.setResourceInfo(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:255)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:538)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:575)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:380)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:220)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
|#]
```

What I don't understand is, why it's looking for the resource `jdbc/resmandb__pm`.  It takes whatever name I bind to (which in this case was `resman`) and adds a `_pm` to it.

What am I doing wrong?  There's not much to this application, and it runs as is in a Glassfish 3 server.

Edit: I've been doing some playing in a standalone glassfish environment.  And, when I don't have an entry for the jdbc resource in glassfish-web.xml, it looks like the JPA provider (in this case, EclipseLink) is looking for two jdbc resources: jdbc/_*pm and jdbc/*_nontx, where  is the name of the resource declared in web.xml.

So, I haven't tried yet, but it looks like I would need to define this in the bees-web.xml, which CloudBees own documentation is trying to get people to not use.  Unforunately, the resource binding isn't working very well with GlassFish 3 environments.  That's what I'm finding so far.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a resource to application, you have to use the --alias parameter to configure the logical name it will use in application. For a datasource, if you have a resource-ref in wen.xml as :

```
   <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

then bind datasource as :

```
bees app:bind --database  myDatabase --alias myDB
```

Comment: Hmmm.  I just tried this.  And it did not make a difference.  Still getting the following error :(

Comment: [#|2013-03-01T22:44:35.336+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;|Exception while preparing the app|#]

[#|2013-03-01T22:44:35.337+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;|Invalid resource : jdbc/resmandb__pm
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/resmandb__pm
 at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:540)
 at

Comment: And, there's nowhere in my code that uses __pm for the jdbc address, and I used the alias.  I'm stumped