# JNDI resource name appended with __pm . Deployment fails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, ear

I am trying to run a very simple ear applicaiton . i seem to run into exactly this issue but the discussions here dont work for me  [JDBC resource name being modified by container (`__pm` being appended to it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065661/jdbc-resource-name-being-modified-by-container-pm-being-appended-to-it)

In my case also the datasource name is being appened by `__pm`. I have no clue where it comes from but the server logs point to the fact that instead of searching for `databasename` it searches for `databasename__pm` and fails the deployment.

Persistence.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="FCK-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>FCKDatabase</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Glassfish logs :

```
  Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/jdbc/FCKDatabase__pm), (applicationName=FCK) }. Please see server.log for more details.
        Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method : java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/jdbc/FCKDatabase__pm), (applicationName=FCK) }
        Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/jdbc/FCKDatabase__pm), (applicationName=FCK) }
```

As you can see my the JNDI name of my resources is appened with `__pm`.

Also on the Glassfish server console the resource is correctly shown as FCKDatabase and not FCKDatabase_pm

Any idea where this `__pm` comes from ?

System:

- Netbeans 7.3
- Glassfish Server 3.1.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that the mysql connector jar file was not placed into the glassfish server. This kicks in a series of problems. The one that I posted above is just one of the error messages that the server logs contains. I suggest going through the entire list of error message and try to debug from there. The following link helped me place the jar files at the correct location:

- [Connecting a MySQL database to Glassfish classpath is not set or classname is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349970/connecting-a-mysql-database-to-glassfish-classpath-is-not-set-or-classname-is-wr)
- [Blog Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource](http://bhapca.blogspot.sg/2009/06/class-name-is-wrong-or-classpath-is-not.html)

Comment: i placed the connector on both lib and ext folders but still i have the same problem with deploying my war..

Comment: Restarting & refreshing server should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since Netbeans 7.1 when the IDE generates the `persistence.xml` the `jta` field and `glassfish-resouces` JDNI name is generated with a prefix `java:module/`, it has to be deleted in both files, it has to look like `jdbc/[anyName]`. This was tested on Netbeans 8.1 and Glassfish 4.0.

[In the image, the second option shows the generated name, which is invalid en Glassfish because the ':'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rw9q.png)

Comment: If it that's not working either, make sure to copy the mysql-connector in the right place on Glassfish:  Glassfish/glassfish/domains/{your_domain}/lib

Comment: This worked for me, but only for the jdbc/sample default DB, i couldn't use my own. But anyway for what i needed it was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which I have found, it will be helpful to anyone.

Copy the resource name which you are facing the problem and follow the below steps.

1. Login into Glassfish console
2. Goto Resources
3. JDBC --> JDBC Resources
4. Click on New button to add resource
5. Enter the copied resource into JNDI name field and select the pool name and enter the description.
6. Click on Ok button

Redeploy the application and check.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just moved my `glassfish-resources.xml` file,

**from:**

my_web_app / src / main / **webapp / WEB-INF**

**to:**

my_web_app / src / main / **setup**

And GlassFish started to recognize the file the created the resources.